# Flink crash with “java.lang.IllegalArgumentException” after I fetch some data to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a Flink program consuming a Kafka topic. I use Spark to send some message(JSON String I copied from the topic) to the topic (what I want to do is to manually trigger the flink computation). Then the Flink crashed instantly with following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:275)
    at kafka.message.Message.sliceDelimited(Message.scala:236)
    at kafka.message.Message.payload(Message.scala:218)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.SimpleConsumerThread.run(SimpleConsumerThread.java:338)
```

Anyone can tell me why this happened and how to resolve it ?

There is the spark code I use to write json string to Kafka:

```
 // Connect Kafka
    println("Connecting kafka")
    val KAFKA_QUEUE_TIME = 5000
    val KAFKA_BATCH_SIZE = 16384
    val brokerList = "kafka05broker01.cnsuning.com:9092,kafka05broker02.cnsuning.com:9092,kafka05broker03.cnsuning.com:9092"
    val props = new Properties
    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")
    props.put("partitioner.class", "utils.SimplePartitioner")
    props.put("metadata.broker.list", brokerList)
    props.put("producer.type", "async")
    props.put("queue.time", "5000")
    props.put("batch.size", "16384")
    val config = new ProducerConfig(props)
    val producer = new Producer[AnyRef, AnyRef](config)
    // Send Kafka
    println("Sending msg to kafka")
    val topic = "xxxxxx"
    val msg = "xxx" 
    for (i <- 0 to 1000) {
      println(i)
      val randomPartition = "" + new Random().nextInt(255)
      val message = new KeyedMessage[AnyRef, AnyRef](topic, randomPartition, msg)
      producer.send(message)
    }
```

There is the how I consume in flink:

```
 val allActProperties = kafkaPropertiesGen( GroupId,  BrokerServer, ZKConnect)
 val streamComsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer08[TraitRecord](topic, new TraitRecordSchema(), allActProperties)
 val stream: DataStream[TraitRecord] = env.addSource(streamComsumer ).setParallelism(12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of kafka you are using?It's seems the kafka jar version is not corresponding to your kafka version.Or FlinkKafkaConsumer08 is not  corresponding to your kafka version?Visit 
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException kafka console consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197432/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-kafka-console-consumer)